# tabBarController:PresentModelViewController not working

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios5

I am developing a iPAD app with a UITabViewController and some custom controllers initialized in the  App Delegate.
I would like to show a Login screen to be shown before the user can get to the tabbar controller. However, when I try to present the LoginController modally, It doesn't show up on the screen.
See the code below:

```
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
[[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];

LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[[self tabBarController]presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:NO];
```

The screen now only shows the tabBarController? What am I doing wrong?
If I add the loginVC using  `[[self window]setView:loginVC.View]`, I see the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your code is not working, but

Have your try this?

```
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController presentModalViewController:loginVC
                                                                animated:NO];
```

(Just to be sure you did at some point: `self.tabBarController = tabBarController` so your tabBarController isn't just a local variable and `self.` really get to it.)

Comment: Vince, I just figured out how to make it work.. I was calling presentModelViewController before making the tabBarController Visible on the screen ie before [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] once I shifted the presentModalViewController call to after the window and  UITABBArController are made visible, it worked correctly - I think this modal call will only work after the View itself is visible... I spend whole day today on this. - Anyway I appreciate you taking time to answer this.